# How to fix an escaped JSON string (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json

A remote server (out of my control) send a JSON string which has all fieldnames and values escaped.
For example, when I do JSON.stringify(res), this is the result:

```
"{\"orderId\":\"123\"}"
```

Now when I do alert(res.orderId), it says undefined. I think it's because of the escaped "s.
How do I fix this?

Comment: What's shown if you `console.log(res)`? See, I really fail to understand why do you _stringify_ the result instead of _parsing_ it.

Comment: give the code what fires the bug.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Assuming that *is* the actual value shown then consider:

```
twice_json = '"{\\"orderId\\":\\"123\\"}"'  // (ingore the extra slashes)
json = JSON.parse(twice_json)               // => '{"orderId":"123"}'
obj = JSON.parse(json)                      // => {orderId: "123"}
obj.orderId                                 // => "123"
```

Note how applying JSON.stringify to the `json` value (which is a *string*, as JSON *is text*) would result in the `twice_json` value. Further consider the relation between `obj` (a *JavaScript object*) and `json` (the JSON *string*).

That is, if the result shown in the post is the output from `JSON.stringify(res)` then res is *already* JSON (which is *text / a string*) and *not* a JavaScript object - so don't call stringify on an already-JSON value! Rather, use `obj = JSON.parse(res); obj.orderId`, as per the above demonstrations/transformations.

Comment: You're right. For some reason all other Google APIs returned an object, but now this API returned a string that I had to JSON.parse() myself.

Answer (score 9):

the accepted answer not work for me.
I use

```
json = json.replace(/\\/g,"");
let arrayObj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: Should mention why the answer didn't work for you (i.e. how it fails)

Comment: What is `json` here? There's no replace for the standard JSON object in js...

Comment: in some case. the string contain "\" symbol, so I need to trim them.

Comment: I recomend using str.replace(/\\"/g, '"') here

Answer (score 1):

It's actually an object that you execute JSON.stringufy on it.

```
var jsonString = "{\"orderId\":\"123\"}";
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

console.log(jsonObject.orderId);
```

Or you do simple than that

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse("{\"orderId\":\"123\"}");
console.log(jsonObject.orderId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggested solutions provide an answer to the specific problem in the question but can't fix overly escaped JSON in a generic way.

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
const veryEscapedJsonString = "\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"potato\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"salad\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\""

function jsonParseUntilUnescaped(escapedJson) {
    const parsedJson = JSON.parse(escapedJson)
    const stringifiedParsedJson = parsedJson.toString();

    if (stringifiedParsedJson.includes('\"')) {
        return jsonParseUntilUnescaped(stringifiedParsedJson )
    }

    return parsedJson;
}

const json = jsonParseUntilUnescaped(veryEscapedJsonString);

// { potato: 'salad' }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JSON.parse, I don't really know what that API returns for you so I can't give you alternatives.

```
var res = "{\"orderId\":\"123\"}";
res = JSON.parse(res);
alert(res.orderId);
```

Comment: Ok, I'm going to double check with your solution.

Answer (score -4):

Do you really need to stringify your data can not juste use json.orderId ? you say send you a json string ? you have not to do stringify if your json is already in string.... if you have chrome debugger or another browser debugger you can see the type of your var...

Comment: No I don't, but I pasted the stringify here to show that the "'s are escaped. Normally you wouldn't see those backslashes with stringify. I think it's the reason why res.orderId returns undefined.

Comment: have you tried $.parsedJSON(yourjson) ? i repeat if it is already in string format it is normal you can not play with json data !sometimes following the way to send or retrieve the data you have to do it manually