# How can we acces "meta" value of string in this api data response

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, string, api

I want to acces id's from data.board.meta and use it for anchor tag in react framework. My left side drawer is showing nested listing and with onClick I want to access the id of that card and then want to render its board and scroll to the selected card.

```
const data = {
  "board": {
      "id": 146,
      "title": "lmlsmdsa",
      "meta": "[{\"id\": \"item-1-1661934790875\", \"card\": [{\"id\": \"card0-1661938324291\", \"cardid\": 360, \"content\": \"<h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2><p><span style=\\\"background-color:rgb(255,255,255);color:rgb(0,0,0);\\\">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam laoreet dolor ut pretium pellentesque. Nam eget pulvinar diam. Sed sit amet risus feugiat, maximus velit quis, vehicula quam. Integer faucibus, enim quis imperdiet pulvinar, est augue dignissim est, a venenatis neque nisi vitae erat. Sed ornare nulla eros, sed lacinia dolor iaculis non. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce vulputate risus eros, maximus cursus tellus commodo sed. Aliquam tempus ligula at dui sollicitudin cursus. Sed suscipit dui volutpat justo venenatis, non condimentum ligula sollicitudin.</span></p>\", \"moduleType\": 1, \"moduleFormat\": 6, \"markasReusable\": false}, {\"id\": \"card1-1667800354494\", \"cardid\": 575, \"content\": \"<p>m</p>\", \"moduleType\": 1, \"moduleFormat\": 6, \"markasReusable\": false}], \"title\": \"Untitled 1\", \"content\": \"Headlines 1\"}, {\"id\": \"item-2-1661948388405\", \"card\": [{\"id\": \"card0-1664363817615\", \"cardid\": 467, \"content\": [{\"date\": \"2022-09-28T11:16:57.615Z\", \"image\": \"\", \"title\": \"chinmay\", \"description\": \"<p>developer</p>\"}], \"isAddNews\": false, \"moduleType\": 7, \"newsvalues\": {\"taskkey1\": {\"date\": \"2022-09-28T11:16:40.112Z\", \"isCreated\": false, \"dynamicKey\": \"taskkey1\"}}, \"moduleFormat\": 6, \"markasReusable\": false}], \"title\": \"Untitled 156\", \"content\": \"Headlines 2\"}]",
      "status": 1,
      "created_by": 4,
      "updated_by": 4,
      "created_at": "2022-08-31T08:33:27.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-11-07T05:52:35.000000Z"
  },
  "users": [
      {
          "id": 1,
          "first_name": "Barir",
          "last_name": "Sih",
          "email": "barir.sih@cet",
          "picture": null
      }
  ],
  "teams": [],
  "message": "Retrieved successfully"
}
```

I'm confused on how to access this kind of data

Comment: You can use `JSON.parse(data.board.meta)`. Object inside `data.board.meta` is stringified so you have to use `JSON.parse` here.

Comment: This  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721227/2122822) should do it for you