# The fieldNames of date-/time-/datetimePickers are changed on mobile (IOS)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a problem with getting the values of form inputs in Gmail apps script add-on on IOS.
The problem is that the names of all date-/time-/datetime pickers in commonEventObject.formInputs are changed.
For example, Birthdate field:

```
CardService.newDateTimePicker()
              .setFieldName('Birthdate')
              .setTitle('Birthdate')
```

fieldInput from commonEventObject on web:

```
{
  "Birthdate": {
    "dateInput": {
      "msSinceEpoch": 1617667200000
    }
  }
}
```

fieldInput from commonEventObject on IOS:

```
{
  "b67f0e6c412057bed9971b0c1413f457Birthdate": [
    "{\"dateTimeMS\":\"1617667200000\",\"hasDate\":true,\"hasTime\":false,\"type\":2}"
  ]
}
```

As you can see the name of the field is changed. `b67f0e6c412057bed9971b0c1413f457` string is inserted into the name of all date/time/date fields.
Besides all info about field (such as `hasDate`, `hasTime` etc) is passed into a string.

Is there a way to get the values form pickers? What is `b67f0e6c412057bed9971b0c1413f457` string and why is it inserted into field names?

Comment: The JSON string just looks escaped, so you should be able to parse it, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721164/how-to-fix-an-escaped-json-string-javascript). As for the random string, it looks like some kind of ID, so it may be a bug. You can extract the name of your field at the end, but this may be something that you can report in Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues)